# Ocr that recognizes this specific image

Tags: windows, java, ocr

I've tried Tesseract, Asprise and Abbyy, but they all fail on this image. Abbyy just gives an empty output and the other two convert the "6" to a "5".
I've also tried on newocr.com, which can't read the text.

[image: 1,642]

I'm trying to create an app that follows poker tables on betfair. A window may typically look like this:

[image]

Betfair seems to use a font that makes it particularly difficult to ocr numbers. I prefer not to use a webapp, as that's too slow (the hands go pretty quick). I'm creating a windows 10 application in Java, so it should be accessible from Java. I wouldn't mind paying a little, but I prefer to stay below $100 or $200.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to train Tesseract to recognize the numbers. It was a lot of work. Each time my program wants to send a rectangle from the screenshot to ocr, it also appends it to a tif file. I uploaded the tif file to http://pp19dd.com/tesseract-ocr-chopper/?i=ocregJRk6 to get the initial boxes around each character. Then I edited the resulting .box file in eclipse while looking at the results in jTessBoxEditor. This seemed the best way to go. I needed to gather lots of pieces of code from the internet to get it all working, but it's working now :)

Comment: So, what exactly does your program do?

Comment: I'm trying to follow each hand on the table. Right now it can recognize all cards on the table once they're shown. Most of the time it also correctly logs that someone places a bet/raises (and the amount), but sometimes it's tricky.

Comment: What's the goal, though? Is it to count cards and win games etc?

Comment: Yes, why? I couldn't think of anything else to do with it :).

Comment: It's interesting. Are you getting rich?